# Create Compiled Function

Tags: warning-messages, compile

I am trying to create a compiled version of this function:

```
cKalmanTimeLoop = Compile[{{Y, _Real, 2}, {X, _Real, 2}, {a, _Real, 2}, {b1, _Real, 
2}, {Ve, _Real}, {Vw, _Real, 2}, {Covb1, _Real, 2}},
Module[{Yhat, b, , k, n, e, t, Q, K, Covb, Zscore
(************************************************************)
(************************************************************)
(**UPDATES THE KALMAN FILTER PARAMETERS FOR EACH TIMESTEP**)
(************************************************************)
(*X=k x n matrix of k prices data series for t=1,...,n;
note that X(t)[[1,All]]=1 for all t;
a=k x k State Transition matrix estimated in initialization;
b=k x n matrix of state vectors b(t)={b1,...,bk},Ve=
scalar price error variance,estimated in initialization;
Vw=k x k state noise covariance matrix,estimated in initialization;
Covb[[t]]=k x k state covariance matrix at time t=1,...,n;*)
(***********************************************************)
{k, n} = Dimensions@X;
K = 0.;
e = ConstantArray[0., n];
Q = ConstantArray[0., n];
b = ConstantArray[0., {k, n}];
Covb = ConstantArray[0., {n, k, k}];
b[[All, 1]] = b1;
Covb[[1]] = Covb1;
Do[
(*************************************************)
(*update state prediction and state covariance matrix*)
If[t > 1, b[[All, t]] = a.b[[All, t - 1]];
 Covb[[t]] = a.Covb[[t - 1]].Transpose[a] + Vw;
 Covb[[t]] = DiagonalMatrix@Diagonal@Covb[[t]];];
(*************************************************)
(*Measurement Prediction Equation*)
Yhat = X[[All, t]].b[[All, t]];
(*************************************************)
(*Measurement Prediction Error*)
e[[t]] = Y[[t]] - Yhat;
(*************************************************)
(*Measurement Covariance Prediction*)
Q[[t]] = X[[All, t]].Covb[[t]].X[[All, t]] + Ve;
(*************************************************)
(*Kalman Gain*)
K = Covb[[t]].X[[All, t]]/Q[[t]];
(*************************************************)
(*State Update*)
b[[All, t]] = b[[All, t]] + K*e[[t]];
(*************************************************)
(*State Covariance Update*)
Covb[[t]] = Covb[[t]] - DiagonalMatrix[K*X[[All, t]]].Covb[[t]];
, {t, 1, n}];

 Zscore = e/Sqrt[Q];
{b, Covb, K, e, Q, Zscore}], {{Covb, _Real, 3}}, 
Parallelization -> True, CompilationTarget -> "C"]
```

But I cant seem to get past the following error message:

> Compile::cplist: Compile`$28.Covb[[t]] should be a tensor of type Integer, Real, or Complex; evaluation will use the uncompiled function.

I assume that I am making some elementary syntax error, but I can't spot it.

Also, any suggestions for other possible speed-ups to the code would be gratefully received.

Comment: I debugged this code. How to check (test)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tha Kalman gain is a list, not a scalar here. So, try this (note that I put all variables in lower case, so minor changes):

```
cKalmanTimeLoop = Compile[
    {
       {y, _Real, 2}, 
       {x, _Real, 2}, 
       {a, _Real, 2}, 
       {b1, _Real,2}, 
       {ve, _Real}, 
       {vw, _Real, 2}, 
       {covb1, _Real, 2}
    },
    Module[
        { yhat, b, k, n, e, t, q, capk, covb, zscore},
        (************************************************************)
        (************************************************************)
        (**UPDATES THE KALMAN FILTER PARAMETERS FOR EACH TIMESTEP**)
        (************************************************************)
        (*X=k x n matrix of k prices data series for t=1,...,n;
          note that X(t)[[1,All]]=1 for all t;
          a=k x k State Transition matrix estimated in initialization;
          b=k x n matrix of state vectors b(t)={b1,...,bk},
          Ve= scalar price error variance,estimated in initialization;
          Vw=k x k state noise covariance matrix,estimated in initialization;
          Covb[[t]]=k x k state covariance matrix at time t=1,...,n;*)
        (***********************************************************) 
        {k, n} = Dimensions@x;
        capk = Table[0., {n}]; (* needs to be a vector of length n *)
        e = Table[0., {n}];
        q = Table[0., {n}];
        b = Table[0., {k}, {n}];
        covb = Table[0., {n}, {k}, {k}];
        b[[All, 1]] = b1;
        covb[[1]] = covb1;
        Do[
            (*************************************************)
            (*update state prediction and state covariance matrix*)
            If[ t > 1,
                b[[All, t]] = a.b[[All, t - 1]];
                covb[[t]] = a.covb[[t - 1]].Transpose[a] + vw;
                covb[[t]] = DiagonalMatrix@Diagonal@covb[[t]];
            ];
            (*************************************************)
            (*Measurement Prediction Equation*)
            yhat = x[[All, t]].b[[All, t]];
            (*************************************************)
            (*Measurement Prediction Error*)
            e[[t]] = y[[t]] - yhat;
            (*************************************************)
            (*Measurement Covariance Prediction*)
            q[[t]] = x[[All, t]].covb[[t]].x[[All, t]] + ve;
            (*************************************************)
            (*Kalman Gain*)
            (* NOTE: THIS GIVES A LIST - NOT A SCALAR!!! *)
            capk = covb[[t]].x[[All, t]]/q[[t]];
            (*************************************************)
            (*State Update*)
            b[[All, t]] = b[[All, t]] + capk*e[[t]];
            (*************************************************)
            (*State Covariance Update*)
            covb[[t]] = covb[[t]] - DiagonalMatrix[capk*x[[All, t]]].covb[[t]];
            ,
            {t, 1, n}
       ];
       zscore = e/Sqrt[q];
       {b, covb, capk, e, q, zscore}
   ],
   {{covb,_Real,3}},
   Parallelization -> True, 
   CompilationTarget -> "C"
]
```

You can check with `CompilePrint` which needs the Package `CompiledFunctionTools`.

Comment: Note that there is still code that calls the main-evaluator. I'd have a look at `Diagonal` and `DiagonalMatrix`. These two seem to be one of the reasons and they can be replaced by injected functions.

Comment: Thanks gwr. This works well.  Having said that, it isn't any faster than the WL code, which comes as a surprise (to me).

Comment: @JonathanKinlay There is still `MainEvaluator` being called as halirutan pointed out - that is the reason for example for me using `Table` instead of `ConstantArray`. So there is still some speed gains to be made by optimizing the code.